# Connect Cloudflare tunnel to Nextcloud on the same machine

Tags: docker, ubuntu, cloudflare, nextcloud

I am running nextcloud natively on an ubuntu server machine
and I am connecting my personal domain to Nextcloud via Cloudflare tunnel
The Cloudflare tunnel is running on a docker container on another Ubuntu-Server machine which points to the Nextcloud-UbuntuServer

I am trying to run the Cloudflare Docker container on the same Nextcloud machine:
on Cloudflare when I point the tunnel to the same machine IP address (192.186.0.100) it works, however when I point it to (127.0.0.1) -to save the traffic from going to the router and point back to the same machine, it doesn't work (on the browser Cloudflare tells that it cannot reach the server)

Now I am not an expert and I'm not sure if I am doing things correctly here?

The current setup:
Domain -> Cloudflare -> Ubuntu_Docker_CloudflareTunnel -> Nextcloud

How I want to set it up:
Domain -> Cloudflare -> Docker_CloudflareTunnel_Nextcloud -> Nextcloud ()

[Newsetup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NXvU.png)